# Why is 売っています correct, as opposed to 売ってあります?

Tags: verbs, auxiliaries

As I understand, inanimate objects are referred to using あります. Why, then, is it

> コンビニでお握りを売って**います**

Both subject and object are inanimate. Are we still assuming a salesperson? What if it's a self-checkout store?

Comment: Just a question to the question but shouldn't it be: 
コンビニでお握りが売っています

Comment: After googling: https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/128.html, seems both are ok but が is more commonly heard these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

〜ています is the present continuous. This grammar point requires you convert the verb to て-form and add いる at the end. It means the progressive tense of a verb which shows that something is currently happening or ongoing.

ex

> 田中さんは昼ご飯を**食べています**。Mr Tanaka is eating lunch.

This is the most basic meaning, which shows that someone is currently doing something at this moment.
Here 食べる is converted to its て-form 食べている.　
食べています is the ます-form. It is the polite form of 食べている.

> 毎日、英語を**勉強しています**。I study English every day.

This meaning shows habitual behavior or can be used when talking about something that frequently happens.
勉強する is converted to its て-form 勉強している.

〜ています and 〜います have a similar appearance, but they are different.
〜います is used in existential sentences, and usually preceded by a particle. In fact, my teacher taught me this sentence pattern like this: がいます. The が can be changed to a に/は for places.

I referenced [this site](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-te-iru-meaning/).

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the existing answer, note that the pattern verbて + あります also does exist. It is used with **transitive** verbs to signal that an action has been performed by an actor *intentionally*, and as a result it has reached the current state (see [this](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/tearu/) for reference):

> メモがデスクに置いてある。

> A memo is on the desk. (Nuance: Oh! A memo has been *deliberately* left on the desk.)